# How to set cookies for UIWebView after loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, webview, uiwebview

Here is the situation:
there is a webView in my native app, and some operations need to interact with native app.

e.g.: The follow operation, if user has logged in when follow, then everything goes fine.(the webView knows there is a user logged in according to the existed cookies)

but if user has not logged in yet when follow, then it will present the login View Controller(which is native), and after user finish logging in(will response with the new cookie that mark user as logged-in)，it's expected that follow operation will continue automatically.

The problem is it seems like the webView doesn't know user has logged in without reloading.

Thanks for any suggestions or corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the cookies using this :

```
NSData *cookiesData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]];


NSUserDefaults *defaults    = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject: cookiesData forKey: @"cookies"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: It's not a cookie storage or persistence problem，thanks for the response anyway.